# Expression expected error for SSRS parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I want to pass multiple choices from a filter to my stored procedure. The main parameter which I allow user to choose multiple values named `restCode`. Beside this, I created a new parameter named `multiRestCode` to store multiple choice values as a comma delimited string and then pass this string to my stored procedure. I have set the default value of `multiRestCode` with this expression;

```
=Join(Parameters!restCode.Value, ',')
```

However, I am getting the following error when I try to run the report;

```
The Value expression for the report parameter ‘multiRestCode’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.
```

How Can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a very basic solution. I just replaced the `''` with `""` and report worked.

From this;

```
=Join(Parameters!restCode.Value, ',')
```

To this;

```
=Join(Parameters!restCode.Value, ",")
```